# Processing File Faster than O(MN) Time for Adjacency Linked List Graph

Tags: java, time-complexity

This post is related to my solution on my first post

Now that I have solved the duplicate issue here [my first post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631249/avoiding-duplicates-in-adjacency-linked-list-graph/31631402#31631402), I am wondering if I am able to process my file in faster than O(MN) time (Assuming only loops and walking the file are adding complexity), that is if I am correct in my analysis. This is not a homework question, this is purely my interest.

I say O(MN) because I am walking M lines and chopping it up in N tokens at the worst case for each line. Would this be correct? I originally said O(N^2). Nevertheless, is there a more efficient way?

This method here is a slight improvement on my previous method in terms of clarity, but I would really like to process this file without having to walk the lines and tokenize each line, but I am not that experienced with file processing in order to have that ingenuity nor do I know what to look for. I wish I could see a way to get rid of the nested while loops. Does anybody know of a way to do this? The try-catch blocks are there purely for me to catch issues but will most definitely be removed since this is not a real world implementation nor is it meant to be adaptable.

```
private void processFile(File file)
{   
    Scanner sc;

    /* First we must try to create a scanner from the file */
    try 
    {
        sc = new Scanner(file);

        /* Initializing the hashmap with empty lists in this loop */
        while (sc.hasNext())
        {
            String from = new String();

            /* Here we are skipping over integers for now */
            try
            {
                from = sc.next();
                Integer.parseInt(from);
            }
            /* If parsing the int failed, it must be an airport id */
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                /* Make sure it does not already contain the key in the hashmap */
                if (this.airports.containsKey(from))
                    continue;

                /* Add the key and value to the hashmap */
                AirportVertex source = new AirportVertex(from);
                airports.put(from, source);
                this.numNodes++;
            }
            catch(NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                System.err.println("There are no more tokens available");
            }
        }

        /* Reinitialize the scanner */
        sc.close();
        sc = new Scanner(file);
        String line = new String();
        String from = new String();

        /* Adding adjacent airports */
        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {   
            /* Try to create Scanner for the line read from the file */
            try
            {
                line = sc.nextLine();
                Scanner tokens = new Scanner(line);

                /* Try to read tokens */
                try
                {
                    from = tokens.next();
                }
                catch(NoSuchElementException e)
                {
                    System.err.println("There are no more tokens available to scan for the ");
                }

                /* The first token is the source airport */
                AirportVertex source = this.airports.get(from);


                /* Read the rest of the line */
                while (tokens.hasNext())
                {
                    /* The file has a pattern of alternating strings and ints after the first string read on each line */
                    AirportVertex dest = this.airports.get(tokens.next());

                    int cost = tokens.nextInt();

                    /* You cannot only go one way, must assume both paths */
                    if (!source.adj_lst.contains(dest) && !dest.adj_lst.contains(source))
                    {
                        source.adj_lst.add(dest);
                        dest.adj_lst.add(source);
                        AirportEdge edge = new AirportEdge(source, dest, cost);
                        source.edge_lst.add(edge);
                        dest.edge_lst.add(edge);
                    }

                    /* The destination is now the source for the next destination */
                    source = dest;
                }
            }
            catch(NoSuchElementException e)
            {
                System.err.println("No line could be found");
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.err.println("File could not be found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    printGraph();
    System.out.println("\n");
    printEdgeInfo();
}
```

My output to this code from `printGraph();` and `printEdgeInfo();` is shown here

```
SHV|  OKC SFO DFW
MOB|  DFW ATL
LAX|  HOU LIT DFW
OKC|  MSY SHV DFW
BOS|  ATL DFW AUS HOU
SAT|  HOU DFW AUS
HOU|  DFW SAT BOS LAX AUS
MSY|  LIT OKC DFW
DFW|  BOS MOB AUS HOU ATL SAT LAX SFO LIT MSY OKC SHV
LIT|  LAX MSY DFW
ATL|  BOS DFW AUS MOB
SFO|  SHV DFW
AUS|  DFW ATL BOS HOU SAT


SHV| OKC --> SHV Cost: 59 SHV --> SFO Cost: 1200 SHV --> DFW Cost: 59 
MOB| DFW --> MOB Cost: 59 MOB --> ATL Cost: 59 
LAX| HOU --> LAX Cost: 1000 LAX --> LIT Cost: 59 LAX --> DFW Cost: 1000 
OKC| MSY --> OKC Cost: 59 OKC --> SHV Cost: 59 OKC --> DFW Cost: 59 
BOS| ATL --> BOS Cost: 250 BOS --> DFW Cost: 250 AUS --> BOS Cost: 250 BOS --> HOU Cost: 128 
SAT| HOU --> SAT Cost: 59 DFW --> SAT Cost: 59 SAT --> AUS Cost: 59 
HOU| DFW --> HOU Cost: 59 HOU --> SAT Cost: 59 BOS --> HOU Cost: 128 HOU --> LAX Cost: 1000 HOU --> AUS Cost: 59 
MSY| LIT --> MSY Cost: 128 MSY --> OKC Cost: 59 MSY --> DFW Cost: 128 
DFW| BOS --> DFW Cost: 250 DFW --> MOB Cost: 59 AUS --> DFW Cost: 59 DFW --> HOU Cost: 59 ATL --> DFW Cost: 250 DFW --> SAT Cost: 59 LAX --> DFW Cost: 1000 DFW --> SFO Cost: 100 LIT --> DFW Cost: 59 MSY --> DFW Cost: 128 OKC --> DFW Cost: 59 SHV --> DFW Cost: 59 
LIT| LAX --> LIT Cost: 59 LIT --> MSY Cost: 128 LIT --> DFW Cost: 59 
ATL| ATL --> BOS Cost: 250 ATL --> DFW Cost: 250 ATL --> AUS Cost: 59 MOB --> ATL Cost: 59 
SFO| SHV --> SFO Cost: 1200 DFW --> SFO Cost: 100 
AUS| AUS --> DFW Cost: 59 ATL --> AUS Cost: 59 AUS --> BOS Cost: 250 HOU --> AUS Cost: 59 SAT --> AUS Cost: 59
```

Comment: All your Exceptions except the FileNotFoundException could / should be handled by checking first if an Exception would be thrown (e.g. only convert to int if it really is one) and then doing one or the other instead of using Exceptions and try catch for the logic of your program. You can also always extract stuff, also loops, to methods to add clarity.

Comment: As a note, you can remove every catch(NoSuchElementException e) because your code always calls the next() method after checking if there is indeed a next element.

Comment: I see. Thanks guys. Like I stated, I really just have those there so i could see what was going on at the time of developing it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not O(n²), it is O(n), as you only acess each token a fixed number of times, even if there is a while loop inside another while loop.

For it to be O(n²), for each token you would have to acess all (or a fraction of) other tokens in the Scanner.

Comment: OHHHHH I see, wow nice. It is because it is using an implied iterator correct?

Comment: Wait, but I am reading M lines with worst case N tokens in each line. Even though I am accessing each token fixed amount of times, I am having to read every line and then start back at the beginning of that line and chop it up. The next line isnt read until the entire line has been chopped up, delaying the processing of the file. I can't see why this is O(n)

Comment: At which point in the code do you go back in the line? I only see tokens.next() being called.

Comment: I changed my original opinion to O(MN), I feel like this opinion is a little better. Since you are correct, I am not going back each time. But I am still walking a line at a time and waiting until it has been chopped up. I see where you are coming from. But you are right, it is not happening anywhere near N(N-1)/2 times.